# Gmail's Priority inbox through IMAP?

Tags: php, gmail, imap

I am connected to my GMail account through IMAP (using php_imap)
Is there any way to know if the message is marked as 'important' (thus it is in priority inbox) ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Under the `[Gmail]` folder in IMAP, there is a folder called `Important` which stores all messages marked as important.

I guess you can just check if the message is present in this specific folder.

More information here: http://techcrunch.com/2010/09/03/priority-inbox-imap/